# Why is the UITabBarControllerDelegate nil right after I set it?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have a weird issue involving `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

I am using the following code:

```
import UIKit

class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = MainTabBarControllerDelegate()
        print("did set delegate to \(self.delegate)")
    }

}

class MainTabBarControllerDelegate: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        print("selected: \(viewController) --> index: \(tabBarController.selectedIndex)")
    }

}
```

Then, in my Storyboard I have the vanilla `UITabBarController` with two plain `UIViewControllers` connected to it. I simply want to catch the tab change events, but for some reason the `delegate` of my `MainTabBarController` doesn't get set properly.

When I run the project with the code from above, the console outputs:

```
did set delegate to nil
```

Why doesn't it create a proper instance of `MainTabBarControllerDelegate` so that its delegate methods can be called?

Comment: Delegate properties are typically weak. You have to hold strong reference to your delegate elsewhere to keep it alive.

Comment: ah yes! stupid mistake, thanks!! please add this as an answer instead of a comment so that I can accept it and you get your well deserved points ;) @AntonBronnikov

Comment: Done.  Was AFK (from mobile), so had to be concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `self.delegate = MainTabBarControllerDelegate()` you create a delegate and immediately assign it to the `delegate` property, which is `weak`.  So the delegate gets created but then immediately disposed because there is nothing that holds a strong reference to it.

Comment: I'm curious how you knew that MainTabBarControllerDelegate had a weak reference. Is that a common convention or did you actually inspect the declaration of MainTabBar...?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu, it's not so much of convention rather than necessity with delegate pattern.  Very often delegate and delegator keep reference to each other, and one of these references simply must to be weak in order to avoid reference cycles.  Usually it's the delegate that has a weak reference.