# swift delegation - when to use weak reference, why 'delegate' is nil?

Tags: swift, protocols, delegation

Here is my code:

```
protocol Delegate: NSObjectProtocol {}

class A: NSObject {
    weak var delegate: Delegate!
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    func start() {
        //synchronous------- print A: false
        print("A:", delegate == nil)

        //asynchronous------- print B: true  Why is 'true'? How can do that not be released?
        let time: NSTimeInterval = 1
        let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(time * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("B:", self.delegate == nil)
        }
    }
}

class B: NSObject, Delegate {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        let a = A()
        a.delegate = self
        a.start()
    }
}
```

I searched for other questions on stack overflow but I can't find something that can help me to fully understand this situation.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608397/why-is-the-uitabbarcontrollerdelegate-nil-right-after-i-set-it/34608887, perhaps it's a similar case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class A you defined the delegate to be **weak**. This means that if no other object refers to the delegate object (instance of class B in your case), then this instance can be released.

In the beginning of the run, the instance of class B was reference by some object. In this class B you created class A instance, and assigned class B instance as its delegate. 
When you printed the delegate value, it was not nil.

Later, the instance of class B was not references any more by other object, beside the class A instance. Since class A instance referred to it as **weak**, its reference was not count, and instance A was released from memory. This is why when you printed the delegate value one second later it was nil.

**Why to use weak**? 
If you were not using weak, then class A instance would hold a reference to class B instance, and class B instance would hold a reference to class A instance. This way the reference counting of both instances will be greater than 0, and none of them could be freed!!! This will cause a memory leak. What you want is that if no other object is referencing the class B object it will be released from memory, and hence class A object could be release as well.